# JQuery Slider SetInterval Repeatedly Set Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, intervals

I'm using Jquery UI Slider to update the refresh rate of the div shown. This is in an infinite loop (for photos). It doesn't seem like the divs are following the slider value upon change.

```
var setSpeed = 1000;
var interval;

function makeTimeout() {
    $('#currentCount').html(i+1); // do actions, etc
    interval = setTimeout(function() {
    makeTimeout();
  }, setSpeed);
}

// start loop
  makeTimeout();

// slider update
$("#slider").slider({                   
  value: 0,
  min: -1000,
  max: 1000,
  step: 100,
  change: function(event, ui) {
    clearTimeout(interval);
    var setSpeed = ui.value;
    makeTimeout();
  }
});
```

What happens when I move the slider is that the div#currentCount repeatedly refreshes very fast - but does not do so in relation to the slider's value.

How do I update the Javascript so that (infinitely looping), the interval can be either fast or slow - depending on each repeated slider slidestop?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you change `var setSpeed = ui.value;` to `setSpeed = ui.value;`?

Comment: i'm trying that right now, it looks like it works but i swear my JS feels like it's in some wonky time delay alternate universe when it isnt

edit: i'm trying to understand if this has an end of life built in? or is it infinite loop? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by wonky time delay universe? If you keep sliding, the div will never refresh, if that's what you mean. You can always stop the loop by calling `clearTimeout(interval)`.

Comment: I mean if the sliding stops, the loop would be infinite? thanks Royce